# Multiple $(document).ready functions

Tags: jquery, html

If I have multiple `$(document).ready(...)` functions, do they overwrite each other? For the sake of argument, pretend proper coding is thrown out the door on this one.

Say I have a `$(document).ready(function() {...});` in my site's script file. Then I use a third party plugin that also uses `$(document).ready(function() {...});`. Will this overwrite my already created function or does jQuery "queue" these functions to all run when the document is ready?

Comment: No, just keep this in mind if you're using it a lot: http://encosia.com/dont-let-jquerys-document-ready-slow-you-down/

Comment: @PaulPRO - Great link. I never thought about that.

Comment: @Spidy: did you even look a the suggested questions when creating this question? There is a ton of these questions already. It's a direct duplicate of about 5 other questions.

Comment: @Alastair - I did a search and looked at the suggested questions. I always do. Not my fault stackoverflow didn't show them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, they do not override each other. Each function is executed.

You could of course check this easily yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/6jgGt/

Or understand from the [jQuery code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L255) itself:

Line 255 is the ready function where the `jQuery.bindReady();` is called which among other things initialises the `readyList` object on line 429 with `readyList = jQuery._Deferred();`

And once it's a deferred object the function passed in is *appended* with `readyList.done( fn );` and we can see [in the `done` method](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/deferred.js) on line 41 that the element is added to an array with `callbacks.push( elem );` so each one is saved separately...

Comment: sorry for resurrecting this, but, are the two document ready calls hoisted up into one call when it is interpreted by the browser, or are they literally queued and called one after the other?

Comment: @Panomosh The latter.

Answer (score 4):

No, they don't overwrite each other. They are queued, like you said.