JQuery - use static file in getscript
In one of my script, I'm using
$.getScript("https://rawgit.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.js").then(() => {...});

to get a script before going on.
Loading this script via https is very time consuming so I saved this file to my static folder in django as jquery-editable-select.min.js
how can I use my static js file instead of the https:// url inside $.getScript ?
I tried
$.getScript("{% static 'my/path/from/static/folder/jquery-editable-select.min.js'%}").then(() => {...});

but it's not working

I understand why you would need getScript() if you're getting it through https, but I'm not seeing why you would need to if you've saved the script.  Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/38481699/10951070 to see what I mean.
